# Is it possible to implement an NSSegmentedControl with SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to use Cocoa's [NSSegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from SWT. Is this possible? If not, what can I do to add this functionality to SWT (I see an `NSSegmentedCell.java` file in the widgets package, but this doesn't seem to be usable without `NSSegmentedControl`)?

Comment: Please describe what functionality you want to use exactly/what result to achieve? May be it is already implemented in JFace?

Comment: I'd like to use the native OS controls to make radio button-like functionality. NSSegmentedControls work better than radio buttons in some cases and I'm hoping there's a way to use them from SWT.

Answer (score 0):

The Cocoa implementation of SWT does not appear to use this control, presumably because there is nothing similar on the other platforms.

It looks like you might be able to use the low level code on the the Cocoa version of `org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS` to interact with this control. So for example

```
long class_NSSegmentedControl = OS.objc_getClass("NSSegmentedControl");
```

should get a reference to the control class. However I am not aware of any documentation on this so you would just have to learn how to do things from the SWT source. Of course this is only going to work on Macs.

Comment: I actually tried to create controls this way, and it works, but the control disappears after a few seconds, and I don't know how to get events. I guess I just have to study SWT's source more.